# How to run a Java class file with a jdk binary?

Tags: java, .class-file

I have downloaded jdk binaries (`jdk.tar.gz`) of different JDK versions, say `8u92, 8u121` and `8u131` in a directory.

I want to run a Java program in each of these java versions and know the output. Is there a way to do this?

Something like extract `jdk.tar.gz`, put the class file somewhere in the jdk and execute?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: More like extract then `pathToJdk/bin/java pathToYourClassFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easy way is to extract the three JDK versions, put the .class files in each folder, run the terminal/cmd from each folder and use `java.exe MainClass`
This way you are not using the java executable in your classpath but the java executable in the folder you are currently in

Comment: Thanks Raffolox . 
I use Linux. So extracting the jdk binary, copying the class file in it and running using `./bin/java MainClass` just worked !

Answer (score 1):

You may do following:

- Extract each `jdk.tar.gz` in different folder(say `8u92`, `8u121` and `8u131`).
- Write a small script to run class files with different `JRE version`. Following is a script for windows platform:

  `@echo OFF
   setlocal
   set JDK_8U92=&lt;PATH_OF_JDK_U92_FOLDER_WHERE_IT_IS_EXTRACTED>
   set JDK_8U121=&lt;PATH_OF_JDK_U121_FOLDER_WHERE_IT_IS_EXTRACTED>
   set JDK_8U131=&lt;PATH_OF_JDK_U131_FOLDER_WHERE_IT_IS_EXTRACTED>
   %JDK_8U92%/bin/java.exe %1 >%1_JDK_8U92.txt
   %JDK_8U121%/bin/java.exe %1 >%1_JDK_8U121.txt
   %JDK_8U131%/bin/java.exe %1 >%1_JDK_8U131.txt
   endlocal
   @echo ON`
- Save the script file. Here I assume file name is `MultiJDKExecute.bat`.To run a class file name `Abc.class`, run command `MultiJDKExecute.bat Abc`
- Now you can see the respective out put in <ClassName>_JDK_8U_<JDK Version>.txt

**Note:** If you wish to see output on screen then remove the option `>%1_JDK_8U<JDK Version>.txt` from each lines.